# LDAP custom attribute cannot be searched?

Tags: attributes, ldap, directoryservices

I have some special custom attributes with my ldap setup. I have a custom attribute called "GroupCode". I have bunch of entries with this special attribute that I was able to write to the ldap database. Lets say that I have an entry with attribute "xyz" and another attribute with "wasd". I search with the filter "(GroupCode=xyz)" and  "(GroupCode=wasd)" neither one of these search return anything. However, if I change the filter to "(GroupCode=*)", then it would return all the entries that have the GroupCode attribute. I have examined the attribute properties, and it looks normal, the apache directory studio shows it to be of "String" value, do I don't know why it isn't searching with the filter I provided. My knowledge with ldap structure is fairly limited as it is fairly complexed. Anyone have any idea, please let me know. Much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for your issue is that you forgot to specify the EQUALITY and SUSBSTR properties of your custom attribute.

Here is an example for a custom attribute called sAMAccountName:

```
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
    NAME 'sAMAccountName'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

can you see if you can formulate the same search criteria into an ldapsearch command in the command line?

`ldapsearch -H ldap://LDAP_SERVER -D LDAP_AUTH_LOGIN -b LDAP_BASE -w PW  -x "CRITERIA"`

if so, then you can then also experiment with your criteria.

`ldapsearch -H ldap://LDAP_SERVER -D LDAP_AUTH_LOGIN -b LDAP_BASE -w PW  -x "(GroupCode=xyz)"`